# get selected row in a datatable in an interactive document using Rmarkdown and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

I am exploring the use of `DT:datatable` in an interactive document using Rmarkdown and shiny (I have not used `datatable` before).

I am able to create a document that plots a data table:

````
---
title: "Test DT"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
datatable(iris)
```
````

Clicking in a row in the datatable highlights a row.  Is there any way to access the selected rows without implementing a shiny server? How?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use an output$id for it to work. Just how you would do it in shiny itself

````
---
title: "Test DT"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}

library(DT)

DT::dataTableOutput('irisTable')
output$irisTable = DT::renderDataTable(iris, selection = 'multiple')

p("By default DT allows multiple row selection. Selected rows are...")
renderPrint(input$irisTable_rows_selected)

```
````

DT also allows column and cell selection as well as preselection. See [documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html)